# When is a good idea to declare nested static class over non static nested class?

Tags: java, static-classes

I know the meaning of *nested static classes*, but found it confusing sometimes deciding when to declare them over *non static* nested classes.

**Is it mainly when instantiation wouldn't be a good sense?**

What are the general rules of thumb helping you decide when to use *static* modifier?

Comment: This answer should be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/70613/5221346

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. I would try to explain it to you.

> A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested
>   classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing
>   class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not
>   have access to other members of the enclosing class.

Basically, a **static nested class interacts with the instance members** of its top-level class, just like any other classes.

So, basically you can and should consider a static nested class as a top-level class which has been nested inside another **top-level class just for packaging convenience.**

So whenever you are using a nested class, **start by making it static**, and then see if you need to access any instance members thereby having an opportunity to make it non-static.

Take the example from JDK,

```
public class LinkedList<E> ... {
...

 private static class Entry<E> { ... }

}
```

Here, the `Entry` is a static nested class as it doesn't make any sense for this class to be a top-level class as it is used by the `LinkedList` class only. And since it doesn't even use any members of the `LinkedList` class, thus **making is static makes even more sense**.

Answer (score 2):

always use static. if you need to access members from the outer class use non static

Edit: a good explanation can be found here https://sonar.spring.io/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2694|s=createdAt|asc=false

Comment: Thats a good rule of thumb; but maybe some more explanations wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `static` field, method or class when ever you can and the code still compiles and works correctly.

If the code wouldn't compile or not work if you made it static, don't make it static.

Comment: I think the question is asking just about classes, not fields and methods

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a static class when you don't want the class to access non-static (or instance) fields of the top-level class and the top-level class doesn't need an instance of it.

Always use a `static` inner class unless you can't use a non-static class. This keeps the code simpler and it's more memory efficient.